# Is it possible to return IEnumerable of anonymous objects from DataContext.ExecuteQuery?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, anonymous-types

I develop a reporting engine where reports are based on templates. Every template has string with SQL query and every report has specific values for SQL query parameters. To render a report I set parameters and call [DataContext.ExecuteQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executequery.aspx) method to get list of records. But to catch returned columns I have to know their names and have a class with corresponding properties.

Is it possible somehow to return IEnumerable of anonymous objects from DataContext.ExecuteQuery and then determine their properties using Reflection?

I need a LINQ equivalent for [SqlDataReader.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalues.aspx).

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Until we have C# 4.0 with **dynamiс** keyword we can use this solution (slightly modified code from an article [Executing arbitrary queries in LINQ to SQL](http://geeks.ms/blogs/ohernandez/archive/2008/01/30/executing-arbitrary-queries-in-linq-to-sql.aspx) by Octavio Hernández Leal):

```
public static class DataContextExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> ExecuteQuery(this DataContext dataContext, string query)
    {
        using (DbCommand command = dataContext.Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = query;
            dataContext.Connection.Open();

            using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        dictionary.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i));

                    yield return dictionary;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This extension method returns IEnumerable of Dictionary<> objects where keys are names of query columns.

Comment: Worked great on a system we are still using 12 years later...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it.
Please have a look at this snippet.

```
class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var persons = new Person[]{
                new Person{Age=22,Name="John Doe",Id=1},
                new Person{Age=23,Name="Jack Smith", Id=2},
                new Person{Age=34,Name="Sara Parker", Id=3}
            };
            var anonData = GetAnonTypes(persons);
            foreach (var item in anonData as IEnumerable) {
                //use reflection to access propties 
            }
        }
        static object GetAnonTypes(IEnumerable<Person> persons) {
            var query=from p in persons  select new{
                Id=p.Id,
                Name=p.Name
            };
            return query;        
        }
    }

    public class Person {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help. I need IEnumerable of anonymous objects from DataContext.ExecuteQuery which wants some type as parameter.