# How to work with objects of unknown type returned from DataContext.ExecuteQuery

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, dynamic, executequery

So, with the advent of the dynamic keyword in C# 4.0 I am hoping I can find a better solution to the problem of dealing with types returned by `DataContext.ExecuteQuery` when arbitrary columns are selected.

In the past I have either created a new type to hold the result of such a query or used the method described [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863030/is-it-possible-to-return-ienumerable-of-anonymous-objects-from-datacontext-execut).  So, now that I am able to work on a new project running under .NET 4.0, I looked into using a dynamic type to accomplish the same thing in a less painful manner.

So, I gave this a shot:

```
var result = _db.ExecuteQuery<dynamic>( "SELECT CustomerID,City FROM Customers", new object[0] );
foreach( var d in result )
{
    MessageBox.Show( String.Format( "{0}, {1}", d.CustomerID, d.City ) );        
}
```

An exception is thrown at runtime because the property CustomerID does not exist for the dynamic object.  So, since my experience with the dynamic keyword to this point is nil (an article/blog post or two, no real experience) I was hoping someone here could let me know if what I am trying to do here is even possible.  I am probably overestimating the amount of 'magic' behind ExecuteQuery, but I thought this may work due to the property mapping done behind the scenes.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More recently, we've written [dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), which fits the original question beautifully:

```
var result = connection.Query( "SELECT CustomerID,City FROM Customers");
foreach( var d in result )
{
    MessageBox.Show( String.Format( "{0}, {1}", d.CustomerID, d.City ) );        
}
```

It allows parameters etc, and there is a (preferred) typed API via `Query<T>` - but the `dynamic` API works fine too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for coming back to this Marc.  I am not working on this project anymore, but I have bookmarked the link in case it comes up in the future (I'm a systems guy, not a lot of C#/SQL in my day-to-day work).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The mapping is done by inspecting the `T` and using reflection - and `dynamic` is *really* just a fancy word for `object` in this context. For now, you may have to just create the type that matches the expected layout.

You could *try* passing in `Tuple<int,string>`, but I haven't tried this, and I'm not sure it will realise to map ctor arg 0 to col 0, etc.

I use code like in the question quite a bit, and creating a meaningful stub class usually isn't a problem, especially with automatically implemented properties.

Comment: Thanks Marc.  Creating a stub class is fine, it's not a big deal due to how rarely the situation comes up.  I've honestly never had to use ExecuteQuery because I haven't worked on any applications that required it (I'm a systems guy by trade, not a ton of DB work day to day).  Thanks again, I thought that maybe I was missing something that a more experience DB/LINQ dev. may know.

Comment: Unfortunately passing Tuple<> as the type argument for ExecuteQuery does not work for me...

Comment: @jaraics - here's something then; in the interim we've written "dapper"; and dapper has non-generic `Query()` which returns `dynamic`