# Linq SELECT with ExecuteQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I get the error:

> The type 'System.Int32[]' must declare a default (parameterless) constructor in order to be constructed during mapping.

With the code:

```
var gamePlayRecord = db.ExecuteQuery<int[]>("SELECT UserID, IPID, GameID FROM ArcadeGames WHERE ID = " + gamePlayRecordID).Single();
var userID = gamePlayRecord[0];
var ipID = gamePlayRecord[1];
var gameID = gamePlayRecord[2];
```

I know this is wrong, but can someone show me how to do it correctly without needing to create a new object preferably?

Comment: Just a wild guess - have you tried `List<int>`?

Comment: I've got to ask, what's the compelling reason you don't want to have the `class`?

Comment: refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738512%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#_ESQL

Comment: @WebWorld, and `DbDataRecord` is also an `object`. It has an indexer, but it's not an array.

Answer (score 9):

Result of this query is not `int[]` but one row with numbers.

not good solution: use for every number:

```
int userID = db.ExecuteQuery<int>("SELECT UserID FROM ArcadeGames WHERE ID = " + gamePlayRecordID).Single();
int ipID = db.ExecuteQuery<int>("SELECT IPID FROM ArcadeGames WHERE ID = " + gamePlayRecordID).Single();
int gameID db.ExecuteQuery<int>("SELECT GameID FROM ArcadeGames WHERE ID = " + gamePlayRecordID).Single();
```

or Create sql query

```
db.ExecuteQuery<int>(@"
SELECT UserID FROM ArcadeGames WHERE ID = {0}
UNION ALL
SELECT IPID FROM ArcadeGames WHERE ID = {0}
UNION ALL
SELECT GameID FROM ArcadeGames WHERE ID = {0}", 
gamePlayRecordID).ToList();
```

or Create class ...

Comment: +1 as it's the **only answer here** that actually provides a work around in which the OP wouldn't need to build a class. I don't like it because it makes three round trips, but I think it showcases why the OP just needs to put the data into a class.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have misunderstood the question a little bit. But as @goric explained: An ORM mapper wants to map the results to an object. If you don't want an object or class than don't use an ORM mapper, but use the basic SqlDataReader.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserID, IPID, GameID FROM ArcadeGames WHERE ID = " + gamePlayRecordID, connection);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read())
{
  var userID = reader[0];
  var ipID = reader[1];
  var gameID = reader[2];
}
```

Comment: +1 for at least providing a good workaround. Though it doesn't use the `Query` method, it does provide a memory efficient object array for the results.

Answer (score 1):

The ORM, after retrieving the SQL results, tries to create a new instance of the type you specified, and then find properties on that type with the same name as the columns selected in the query. So in your case, it is trying to create a new `int[]` and then set properties on it called `UserId`, `IPId`, and `GameId`.

There are a few issues here. First, when creating the instance, by default a parameterless constructor is used. `int[]` doesn't have one that can be called, and this is the error you are seeing. Assuming it did have one, I expect this code would fail after instantiating it when trying to set a property called `UserId`.

An easy way around this is to create your own class, as others have answered. If you want a way that doesn't need a new type, you could use something like the non-generic `Query` class from the [dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) library (see Marc Gravell's answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5025702/940) post). The Entity Framework also seems to provide some similar functionality using the `ObjectQuery` and `DbDataRecord` classes, as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738512(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Actually, Marc's answer is using Dapper. When leveraging Dapper it puts the values into POCO's, and can't use an array either. Finally, I'm pretty sure that the OP already knows all of the information you provided. Clearly the OP knows how to do this with a `class`, and he knows he'd need the property names to match, he's just trying to find a way around creating the object.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: I try not to make assumptions about what is/isn't understood by the OP, and it isn't obvious from the question what his level of familarity is with the subject. I don't see using an array being a requirement to the answer, my interpretation was that he just didn't want to explicitly have to create a new type. I don't think anything in the answer is overly long-winded or irrelevant.

Comment: When the OP says **without needing to create a new object preferably** then **clearly** the OP knows how to do it by *creating a new object.* His understanding goes that far. What he **doesn't know** is *how to do it with something like an array where a new instance of an object doesn't have to be created.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is and *ugly* hack for doing this:

```
var gamePlayRecord = db.ExecuteQuery<string>(
        "SELECT cast(UserID as nvarchar(10)) + ';' + cast(IPID as nvarchar(10)) + ';' + cast(GameID as nvarchar(10)) as a FROM ArcadeGames WHERE ID = " + gamePlayRecordID
    )
    .Single()
    .Split(';')
    .Select(i => int.Parse(i))
    .ToArray();
```

Works on my machine...

Answer (score 0):

Not answering your question directly, but take care of security...

Your code is *probably* vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, depending on where comes the value for gamePlayRecordID.

To fix, make the SQL query parameterized (or thoroughly validate the input, if comes from "untrusted" sources):

```
db.ExecuteQuery<int>(@"
  SELECT UserID FROM ArcadeGames WHERE ID = {0}
  UNION ALL
  SELECT IPID FROM ArcadeGames WHERE ID = {0}
  UNION ALL
  SELECT GameID FROM ArcadeGames WHERE ID = {0}", 
  gamePlayRecordID).ToList();
```

as the first solution showed... Many of the solutions provided might have the very same security problem.

Answer (score -1):

It should be something like this

```
  var gamePlayRecord = db.ExecuteQuery<ArcadeGames>(@"SELECT UserID, IPID, GameID FROM ArcadeGames WHERE ID = {0}", gamePlayRecordID).Single();

                var userID = gamePlayRecord.UserID;
                var ipID = gamePlayRecord.IPID;
                var gameID = gamePlayRecord.GameID;
```

Code reference taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx

Comment: The OP knows how to do it with a class. He specifically stated he didn't want to do that. He wanted to use the array.

Comment: OP does not want to create new class. but he can use existing class which is already a table.

Comment: No, that's no different. He doesn't want to **create a new object.**

Comment: No, of course not, but you can pretty easily infer his current understanding of the subject based on how the question was asked. C'mon now.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a correct way to do it, because it wants to map it to an object with named properties. Even if you are able to instantiate the array, it will fail trying to map it to the named fields.

If you don't want to create a class for it, but are more interested in creating a dynamic object, you can take a look at dapper orm. Install it via nuget.
you can do something like this:

```
using (var sqlConnection
        = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();

    IEnumerable products = sqlConnection
        .Query("Select * from Products where Id = @Id",
                        new {Id = 2});

    foreach (dynamic product in products)
    {        
        ObjectDumper.Write(string.Format("{0}-{1}", product.Id, product.ProductName));
    }
    sqlConnection.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: Again, Dapper uses POCO's. Even a dynamic object is a POCO. It's just built at runtime. The OP *doesn't want to build an object.*