# I want to execute my linq query which is in string format. Is there any way to execute string as linq to sql

Tags: linq

Is there any way to execute string as linq to sql query like my query is

```
 var anothertest = " where dri.routeId=1";
 var test = "from dri in applicationDbContext.DeliveryRequestItems"+ anothertest + "select dri";
```

how to execute this query take result from table.

Comment: can you explain to us why you want do this?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614545/linq-select-with-executequery help?

Comment: @sgmoore The OP wants to execute string query linq, but the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614545/linq-select-with-executequery execute a simpele Sql Query.

Comment: Actually, I need this to handle multiple filters which dynamically comes so I want to add where clause dynamically in query to execute

Comment: @divya Before you materialise your query you can add as many where clauses as you wish. In other words you can add filters dynamically to your `IQueryable<T>` without any extra code if it is acceptable for you that all the filters will be composed with `AND` operators. If you need  `AND`/`OR` then that's a different story.

Comment: If you need `AND` and `OR` as well then [LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) will be your friend and its [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)