# SQlite.Net.SQliteCommand ExecuteQuery requires class

Tags: windows, sqlite, uwp

I am working on SQlite with Windows Universal App. I have a scenario where the column names are unknown and want to fetch the data from Sqlite table. The method ExecuteQuery in SQlite.Net.SQlite.SQlCommand expects a class name to be passed. I tried with dictionary but no luck it comes as a empty. Anything related this would be helpful. I cant find much document online.

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), sqlpath);
SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand(query);
List<Dictionary<string, string>> datalist =cmd.ExecuteQuery<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

Comment: see [How to work with objects of unknown type returned from DataContext.ExecuteQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5025702/11654)

Comment: @CL: SQlite doesnt come with DataReader. Ur link may will not work for my application.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is actually map it to a list of dynamic objects with SQLite in UWP app, I'm sorry to tell you that SQLite for UWP doesn't support this function.

And [Dapper.Net](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) is now not available for UWP apps.

You can try to use web API/service to solve your problem, for example you can submit your data to the web API, web API uses dapper to get data from your database and pass it back to your app.